# How to delete sheet rows from two specific columns Y & D if cell in column has the word test somewhere in it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 4 sheets that I need to run a vba macro that will search through column Y & D and delete any rows that contain data that has the word "test" somewhere in it. Not case sensitive, so it could be TEST, test, TesT, etc.

Can someone help me draft up some code for that.
What i've got so far. It doesn't work if there is other words combined with test.
And i'd have to make two macros and then run macro one and have macro two run after macro1. Preferably i'd like to just have one script of VBA if that were possible.

```
Sub DeleteRowswithSpecificValue()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("D:D99999")
If cell.Value = "delete" Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Sub DeleteRowswithSpecificValue()
 
Dim cell As Range
 
For Each cell In Range("D:D99999")
    If cell.Value = "delete" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next cell
 
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what you need. Important to conduct the delete after each worksheet loop as that will optimize performance.

```
Sub deleteAllTest()
    Const textToDelete As String = "test"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, aCell As Range, killRange As Range
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set killRange = Nothing
        For Each aCell In Intersect(ws.Range("Y:Y"), ws.UsedRange).Cells
            If InStr(1, aCell.Value2 & ws.Cells(aCell.Row, 4).Value, textToDelete, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If killRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set killRange = aCell.EntireRow
                Else
                    Set killRange = Union(aCell.EntireRow, killRange)
                End If
            End If
            
        Next aCell
        If Not killRange Is Nothing Then killRange.Delete
    
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, I missed the request of of "somewhere in it". I'll update. I don't like like. :)

Comment: @Toddleson updated. Thanks for feedback. I also included an error check if no values found which appeared when I tested.